# Through vs Through the

Tags: prepositions

When should we write "the" after "through"? For example, should we say "through internet" or "through the internet"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The use of "through" is irrelevant. The answer would be the same for any other preposition.

Comment: Depends on context and meaning

Answer (score 0):

The internet is a huge vast area of space, and you can't say that there are 2 internets.
Through the internet is suitable.

Comment: Space is a huge vast area of space. _Stars are huge masses of mainly hydrogen undergoing controlled nuclear fusion, hurtling through ____._